# Get AST of MACRO statements usinc libclang

Tags: python, c, clang, libclang

There are quite a few defined macros in my code that I would like to be able to get the AST of. A statement might look like this:

```
#define maskout_different_softening_flag(x) (x & (1 << BITFLAG_MIXED_SOFTENINGS_IN_NODE))
```

So if `maskout_different_softening_flag` is used then its cursor will be of kind `BINARY_OPERATOR`. I would like to be able to get all the `cursor`s of that macro so I can replace it in the actual code. By using the `PARSE_DETAILED_PROCESSING_RECORD` option I can get the macros in this form

[image]

The only thing that I can see is `extend` but what would be more useful is something similar to `get_children` together with the ability to retrieve these children cursors every time I find a macro used in the code.

Is this possible using `libclang` in `python`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Macro replacements don't correspond to AST nodes. A macro invocation is replaced with a stream of tokens, not necessarily the same stream on each invocation, and there's no requirement that the replacement be an expression or any other well-formed syntactic entity.

If you want `maskout_different_softening_flag(x)` to be a single syntactic entity with a meaningful root node, you should define it as an inline function, not a macro. Macros are much rowdier denizens of the compilation process; they're not going to sit back and let you syntactically analyse their replacement text. By the time the compiler starts to analyse those tokens, the macro itself has vanished without a trace. (Ok, there is a trace, since the source locations of the token might tell you which `#define` they came from. But that's it.)

As far as I know, libclang shows you the source the way a compiler would see it. So it's probably not going to correspond to the model you seem to want to view.

Comment: tough luck, I will try coming up with a custom solution since what I want to do is translate that code (with the macros) into something else.

Comment: @dearn44 i am also looking solution for the same problem.. please let me know if u have found any! Thanks in advance